# CreateProcess executando EXE

Tags: c++, winapi

Tenho uma aplicação, onde o usuário faz upload de um arquivo para o servidor remoto,
este mesmo servidor ao receber este arquivo deve executar esta aplicação.
estou usando o método CreateProcess. 
O problema é, o diretório do arquivo já esta definido em uma std::string , e estou tendo dificuldades pra passar este diretório como parâmetro para o CreateProcess.

Como devo proceder para que esse diretório possa ser passado para o CreateProcess sem erros?

**EDIÇÃO: Agora o código compila, porém o arquivo não é executado...**

```
//o cliente envia remotamente o diretorio onde sera salvo o arquivo
socket_setup.SEND_BUFFER("\nDiretorio remoto para upload: ");
char *dirUP_REMOTE = socket_setup.READ_BUFFER();
std::string DIRETORIO_UP = dirUP_REMOTE; // variavel onde se armazena o diretorio remoto


    //depois do upload essa é a validação para execução do arquivo
if (!strcmp(STRCMP_EXECUTE, EXECUTE_TIME_YES))
{
    std::wstring temp(directory.begin(), directory.end());

    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));
    CreateProcess(NULL, (LPWSTR)temp.c_str(), NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
}
```

Comment: Que dificuldades você está tendo?

Comment: if (!CreateProcess(NULL,/*directory.c_str()*/, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi));

nessa passagem de argumento para o create process /*directory.c_str()*

Comment: Sim, mas o que acontece? Erro de compilação ou execução?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A assinatura de CreateProcess é:

```
BOOL WINAPI CreateProcess(
  _In_opt_     LPCTSTR lpApplicationName,
  _Inout_opt_  LPTSTR lpCommandLine,
  _In_opt_     LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpProcessAttributes,
  _In_opt_     LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes,
  _In_         BOOL bInheritHandles,
  _In_         DWORD dwCreationFlags,
  _In_opt_     LPVOID lpEnvironment,
  _In_opt_     LPCTSTR lpCurrentDirectory,
  _In_         LPSTARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo,
  _Out_        LPPROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation
);
```

Repare que `LPTSTR` é um ponteiro para uma string de `WCHAR` (16 bits por caractere), mas std::string usa `char` (8 bits por caractere). Então, uma solução é utilizar std::wstring ou converter seu std::string para `LPTSTR`.

---

Se `directory` for std::wstring, você pode usar o `directory.c_str()` mesmo.

Ou você pode converter seu std::string para std::wstring e depois usá-lo, exemplo:

```
std::string str = "c:\\Windows\\System32\\calc.exe"; // EXEMPLO
std::wstring temp(str.begin(), str.end());

STARTUPINFO si;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
si.cb = sizeof(si);
ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

CreateProcess(NULL, (LPWSTR) temp.c_str(), NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
```

**Apesar disso**, acho que seria aconselhável utilizar logo std::wstring no seu caso, pois ao que parece seu compilador está configurado para usar a API do Windows com UNICODE.

Comment: como eu faço a conversão de std::string para LPSTR?

Comment: achei esse metodo
LPSTR s = const_cast<char *>(directory.c_str());
porém agora a assinatura do CreateProcess muda

Comment: Eu editei a resposta. Dá uma olhada lá.

Comment: eu tentei usar
  std::wstring temp(directory.begin(), directory.end());
  if (!CreateProcess(NULL, temp, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi));

porém ainda esta dando problemas na conversão pra LPWSTR

Comment: Você tem que usar o temp.c_str() na função.

Comment: estou tendo o seguinte erro: 
argument of type "const wchar_t *" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPWSTR"

Comment: Agora compila, porém o arquivo não é executado. : (

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, a resposta acima está **correta**.
certifique-se de que você esta fazendo as devidas **validações** antes do **CreateProcess**.
Você esta fazendo **upload** para um servidor remoto, certifique-se de que o arquivo foi **devidamente tratado** ao chegar no servidor antes de você tentar executa-lo.
Verifique também se ele foi fechado **"fclose(arquivo)"** antes da criação do **processo**,
se não será impossível sua execução.